# custom validation for telerik date picker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, telerik, datepicker, onblur

I am using telerik date picker. Date format is dd/mm/yyyy. If user enters it as ddmmyyyy then also it will be converted into format as dd/mm/yyyy. Now if user enters something like ddmmyy i.e. if year is only of 2 digits then i want to throw error message for the same to enter date in valid format. Also this date field is not required. So want to show this message if wrong format of date is entered on blur event of date field.

Comment: Isn't the date picker handling it by itself?

Comment: no it doean't for Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC date picker.

Comment: You didn't tag your question asp.net MVC so I assumed asp.net

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and with [this demo from the Telerik Site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/custompopup/defaultvb.aspx) it works if you do ddmmyy or ddmmyyyy by default if you have it set to a culture that commonly uses that style. Ex.  Canadian English or en-CA.

If you have have specified your format as "dd/mm/yyyy" then the user will have to enter it as so or it will appear incorrect.  You could use some java script to convert it to a proper format, but it would be a lot easier to just set up the date picker properly.

Comment: I am using date picker in telerik extensions for ASP.NET MVC where it doesn't accept date entered as ddmmyy. I have used javascript and set format as ddmmyyyy so date entered like this will be converted into format as dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: You could use some javascript to convert the date from ddmmyy to dd/mm/yyyy.